# ACM certificates cross account DNS validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, terraform, amazon-certificate-manager

I have 2 AWS accounts: `dev` and `prod`.

In the `prod` account, I setup a DNS domain (`example.com`), as well as 2 public Hosted Zone: `example.com` and `prod.example.com`. 2 ACM certificates are also issued for these domains `internal.prod.example.com` and `eks.prod.example.com`. Those certificates are correctly validated by DNS.

In the `dev` account, I have created 2 public Hosted Zones: `dev.example.com` and `example.com`. I issued 2 ACM certificates for `internal.dev.example.com` and `eks.dev.example.com` which, as far as I understand need to be validated with the DNS in the `prod` account.

*These certificated are in pending state.*

How can I validate them?

What I did so far:

- I added a NS record called `dev.example.com` in the `prod` account for the `example.com` Hosted Zone. The value of the NS record are the ones of the `dev.example.com` Hosted Zone created in the `dev` account. This is to delegate the ownership of the R53 Hosted Zone in `prod`. See [here](https://theburningmonk.com/2021/05/how-to-manage-route53-hosted-zones-in-a-multi-account-environment/).
- In the `dev` account, the `CNAME` of the requested domain from ACM have been added in the `dev.example.com` Hosted Zone for validation.

The following code is how it's been done (and working) on the prod account.

**Note** - this is a code that I took over, so I'm not aware if any manual steps have been taken.

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "dns-zone" {
  name = "${var.environment}.${var.zone_name}"
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  domain_name       = "*.${var.environment}.${var.zone_name}"
  validation_method = "DNS"
  subject_alternative_names = list("*.internal.${var.environment}.${var.zone_name}", "*.eks.${var.environment}.${var.zone_name}")

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cert_validation" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name    = dvo.resource_record_name
      record  = dvo.resource_record_value
      type    = dvo.resource_record_type
      zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.dns-zone.zone_id
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = each.value.zone_id
}


resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "cert" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.cert_validation : record.fqdn]
}
```

Ps - Should you need more clarification, please let me know.

Comment: dev & prod account you have example.com? Only 1 can be used properly. Wherever the registrar is for example.com can only use the name servers from one of those hosted zones. You mentioned you have 2 ACM certs for internal.dev.example.com & eks.dev.example.com ... those should be validated in the DEV Account if that's where their domains are created. Also I recommend you just create 1 wild card cert in ACM for *.dev.example.com & validate that 1 in the DEV account. Any subdomains such as eks.dev.example.com will be able to use it.

Comment: @paulg - you were right all along. If you want to add your comment as an answer, it would be my pleasure to upvote and accept it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer. Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dev & prod account you have `example.com`? Only 1 can be used properly. Wherever the **registrar** is for **example.com** ... that registrar can only use the **name servers** from 1 of those hosted zones.

You mentioned you have 2 ACM certs for internal.dev.example.com & eks.dev.example.com ... those should be validated in the DEV Account if that's where their domains are created.

Also I recommend you just create 1 wild card cert in ACM for `*.dev.example.com` & validate that 1 in the DEV account. Any subdomains such as eks.dev.example.com will be able to use it.